# Webdeploy publishing file

Tags: webdeploy

I am trying to export my webdeploy publishing file so that the file will have password included in it.  However, every time i do that, it seems like the password that's in the publishing file is invalid. I have to retype the password every time if I use the publishing file on another computer.

I know for a fact that there must be a way to do so, because my Azure account allows me to export my publishing setting from Azure control panel and the publishing setting works on my local computer without having to retype in my password.

Comment: How are you exporting the file?  The password for a publish profile is in the .pubxml.user file, not the .pubxml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that you can use plain text for password in the xml file.  I placed and example before if anyone have the same problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<publishData>
<publishProfile
profileName="smarterasp.net - Web Deploy"
publishMethod="MSDeploy"
publishUrl="https://test-001-site1.smarterasp.net:8172/msdeploy.axd"
msdeploySite="blahblahblah"
userName="blahblahblah"
userPWD="Password_in_plain_text"
destinationAppUrl="http://test-001-site1.smarterasp.net:80/"
/>
</publishData>
```